# react state extend multilevel object not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

state default values

```
state = {
        moveType: {
            value: 0,
            open: false,
            completed: false
        }
    };
```

// callback to update new state

```
let step = 'moveType';
let val = 3; // new value
let newObj = { ...this.state[step], value: val };
console.log(newObj);
this.setState({[step]: newObj }, function () {console.log(this.state);});
```

`console.log(newObj)` shows new values proper, but `this.state` still shows old values.. can you tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, according to documentation, "setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. " (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: @AnthonyKong, according to documentation, "The second parameter to `setState()` is an optional callback function that will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered." Shouldn't callback contain new value?

Comment: You mean `console.log(this.state);` logs the old value? I'm surprised that it logs something at all. Inside the callback, `this` *does not* refer to the react component.

Comment: @FelixKling, okay, change `function()` to `() =>` or use `self` instead of `this` - things will be the same.

Comment: Basil, it's pretty long story how React renders components, but if you will move this code outside of one of event handlers of a `render` function, things will work.

Answer (score 2):

Setting state in react is pretty sensitive thing to do.
The best practices I've used to is always control object deep merge manually and use `this.setState(state => { ... return new state; })` type of call, like in this example:

```js
this.setState(state => ({
  ...state,
  [step]: { ...(state[step] || {}), ...newObj },
}), () => console.log(this.state));
```

**SNIPPET UPDATE start**

`[step]: { ...state[step], ...newObj }`

Changed to:

`[step]: { ...(state[step] || {}), ...newObj }`

To deal correctly with cases, when state does not have this `step` key yet

**SNIPPET UPDATE end**

Thing is, that when you use `this.state` (in `let newObj = { ...this.state[step]`), it might have an outdated value, due to some pending (not merged yet) changes to the state, that you've called just couple of milliseconds ago.

Thus I recommend to use callback approach: `this.setState(state => { ... use state and return new state;})` which guarantees that the `state` you use has latest value

Comment: The result is still the same  with above code sample.  Yes I have couple of milliseconds calls one after another updating same object and I think once its updated once, it does not merge with other..  since it updates the last merged values..

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of the code, showing the way you do these milliseconds calls?